# update one datatable from another after comparing primary key of both

Tags: c#, sql

I have two datatables and each has different 70-80 columns. I want to update the values of one datatable field with other datatable field values which are matching after comparing the primary keys of both in c#.

suppose I have one data table dt1 contains rows and 60 columns.

I have another datatable dt2 contains rows and 70 columns.
and 10 columns of dt1 matches with dt2. 30 rows of dt1 matches with dt2.
so I want to compare the primary key of both datatable and after if they match the update column values from dt1 to dt2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, consider dt1=Customer and dt2=Order, CustomerId exist in both datatables, and i also joined them using LINQ extension method, and finally select columns from both datatables. Thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(); //dt1=Customer
        dt1.Columns.Add("CustomerId", typeof(int));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

        dt1.Rows.Add(1, "Customer A");
        dt1.Rows.Add(2, "Customer B");
        dt1.Rows.Add(3, "Customer C");

        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();  //dt2=Order
        dt2.Columns.Add("OrderId", typeof(int));
        dt2.Columns.Add("CustomerId", typeof(int));  //Fk
        dt2.Columns.Add("OrderDate", typeof(DateTime));
        dt2.Columns.Add("OrderAmount", typeof(double));

        dt2.Rows.Add(1, 1,DateTime.Now,15000);
        dt2.Rows.Add(2, 1, DateTime.Now,10000);
        dt2.Rows.Add(3, 2, DateTime.Now,25000);

        var result = dt2.AsEnumerable()
            .Join(dt1.AsEnumerable(),
            x => x.Field<int>("CustomerId"), //Order(CustomerId) FK
            y => y.Field<int>("CustomerId"),  //Customer Id(Pk)
            (x, y) => new { dt2 = x, dt1 = y })  //dt2=Order, dt1=Customer
            .Select(x => new
            {
                OrderId = x.dt2.Field<int>("OrderId"),
                CustomerId = x.dt1.Field<int>("CustomerId"),
                Name = x.dt1.Field<string>("Name"),
                OrderDate = x.dt2.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate"),
                OrderAmount = x.dt2.Field<double>("OrderAmount"),
            });

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}, CustomerId: {1}, Name: {2}, OrderDate: {3}, OrderAmount: {4}",
                item.OrderId,item.CustomerId,item.Name,item.OrderDate,item.OrderAmount);
        }        

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reference the tables individually unfortunately.

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET 
col2c=(SELECT colc2 FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2_pk=tbl1.tbl1_pk),
col4e=(SELECT cole4 FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2_pk=tbl1.tbl1_pk)
WHERE test.tbl1.tbl1_pk=(SELECT tbl2_pk FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl1_pk=tbl2_pk)
```

[Link to see results in table pre and post execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NByY3.png)